# React-native make an application open webview with url push from notification firebase use react-native-fcm

Tags: react-native, mobile-application, react-native-ios, react-native-fcm

I want make an application use react-native-fcm
https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm

Step 1: Push notification from google firebase with message is an url

Step 2: Click on the notification -> Open URL by Webview

Please help me!